# URI scheme of Google+ iOS app?

Tags: ios, uri, google-plus

I'm working on something cool and I want to link to my Google+ profile in the iOS app.

Has anyone found out how to use the `mgc://` URI scheme that the Google+ app on iOS provides to open a specific profile the way you can do it with `fb://`, `twitter://` and almost every other account-based iOS app?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/api/

Comment: Nope, I'm looking for the URI scheme. The iOS API for actual apps is not useful in this case.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In fact it's really simple. Check your URL in a web browser and replace `http://` or `https://` with `gplus://`

**Example :**

If the URL in your browser is https://plus.google.com/u/0/100711776131865357077 then you open the profile in the app with the following code.

```
NSURL *gPlusUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"gplus://plus.google.com/u/0/100711776131865357077"];

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:gPlusUrl]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:gPlusUrl];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I found the solution [here](http://applookup.com/Home) (just search "google"). The URL scheme is `gplus://`. I have tested this myself and verified that it worked. Usage example:

```
NSURL *gPlusUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"gplus://"];

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:gPlusUrl]) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:gPlusUrl];
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but what I need is a way to directly link to my profile. How would I do that?