# mgc:// ios url scheme for opening the Google+ App in a specific profile

Tags: ios, url-scheme

I need to open an external app. I already did it using url schemes for 
facebook, twitter, instagram and so on. Now I need to open the google plus app. I found over 
the internet the url scheme "mgc://" but I need to inform a specific user profile as I did on 
facebook fb://profile/000000001 for example. My question is: How can I inform the profile to 
open the app in the specific profile? for example mgc://userparameter/identification  I need 
to know the complementation of the url scheme to open the app on a specific profile.  Thanks.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/ios/ i think you have to integrate Google+ with your app

Comment: I read in doc that is possible to retrieve profile information via GTLQueryPlus *query = [GTLQueryPlus queryForPeopleGetWithUserId:@"me"] but I do not need to get information via API, I would like to open the the profile in the Google+ App, not in my app. Anyway Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Possibly duplicate (and answered) of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15434653/uri-scheme-of-google-ios-app/21231485#21231485

Answer (score 0):

According to **http://handleopenurl.com** (a list of schemes which is very useful) you can use one of the following...

- gplus://
- mgc://

I cannot seem to find any parameters for these however so you are quite limited with what you can do with them but it should open the Google Plus app non the less.